# Twitter typeahead.js remote and search on client

Tags: ajax, search, twitter, remote-server, typeahead.js

As of my understanding typeahead.js got three ways of fetching data.

- Local: hardcoded data
- Prefetch: Load a local json file, or by URL
- Remote: Send a query to the backend which responds with matching results

I want to fetch all data from the backend and then 
   process it on the client.
The data my server responds with got the following structure:

```
[{id:2, courseCode:IDA530, courseName:Software Testing, university:Lund University},
{id:1, courseCode:IDA321, courseName:Computer Security, university:Uppsala University}, ...]
```

I want it to search on all fields in each entry. (id, courseCode, courseName, university)

I wanna do more on the client and still fetching one time for each user (instead of every time a user are typing), I probably misunderstood something here but please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should re-read the docs. Basically there are two things you need:

1. Use the `prefetch:` object to bring all the data from the backend to the client only once (that's what you are looking for, if I understand correctly.)
2. Use a `filter` function to transform those results into datums. The returned datums can have a `tokens` field, which will be what typeahead searched by, and can be built from all your data.

Something along the lines of:

```
$('input.twitter-search').typeahead([{
    name: 'courses',
    prefetch: {
        url: '/url-path-to-server-ajax-that-returns-data',
        filter: function(data) {
            retval = [];
            for (var i = 0;  i < data.length;  i++) {
                retval.push({
                    value: data[i].courseCode,
                    tokens: [data[i].courseCode, data[i].courseName, data[i].university],
                    courseCode: data[i].courseCode,
                    courseName: data[i].courseName,
                    template: '<p>{{courseCode}} - {{courseName}}</p>',
                });
            }
            return retval;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you! awesome code snippet, was brightening things up for me. Tried prefetch before but I didn't get it to work.
I just changed the "int i" to "var i" and returned retval after the for loop and it workes!

Comment: Welcome :) Ah. Correct. I am still somewhat used to 'c', and typed this 'blind'. Will edit the response.

Comment: Okey, when I looked more deeply into it I recognized some things that I needed to change. The reason It sometimes didn't work was I was in incognito window in chrome, maybe the local storage is shut of there.
I also had to add a template engine like "engine: Hogan". I also moved "template: '<p>{{courseCode}} - {{courseName}}</p>'" out from the filter and added ".join('')," to it

Comment: What I actually wanted from the beginning was to load the data once every pageload (or when no hit is found in the local data) instead of every key press. Now it didn't updated my data even though I refreshed the page, so if new courses where added the user would never recognize it. However, I added "localStorage.clear();" in my document ready function. That solved it but I would prefer to have it reload the data if it doesn't find it on typing. Maybe I can use remote for that? Will look into it tomorrow, time to sleep now.

Comment: @nilsi: loading once per page is exactly what `prefetch` is for. If you don't specify a `name: "courses"` (i.e.: don't specify a name at all) then it won't be saved in local storage, and you'll get all the updated with every page reload.