# Bootstrap 3 typeahead with external json file not working. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I'm trying to use [Typeahead (for bootstrap3)](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) in Bootstrap 3 in which I want to get the results from an api instead of pre-loading them. So the first step I wanted to try is to load the results from an external file. The way that is done in [this example](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-typeahead.php) is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $('#search-input').typeahead({
        name: 'states',
        prefetch: 'states.json',
        limit: 10
    });
});
```

with my `states.json` containing `["Alabama","Alaska","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"]` and my html being as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="search-input" class="typeahead" style="margin: 0 auto;" data-provide="typeahead">
```

But this doesn't work. I don't get any errors in the console, and I've been breaking my head about this for a while now, but I really can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Does anybody know how I can get this to work? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Can you share the url of the page on which we can see the problem?

Comment: Have you tried this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934991/1910735

Comment: @DawoodAwan - Thanks for the tip. I'm going to try it right now!